# Show DB2 Tables in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, database, oracle, db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

UPDATE: *If anyone knows a tool that is free, and would display, and let me edit DB2 table data stored on a Zos System, I welcome that as an answer too. Really all I'm trying to do is find a nice windows GUI interface to avoid using the 3270 environment.*

---

I'm connecting to a DB2 database with Oracle SQL developer. 
There's several tables in the database, but I don't see them listed when I start the connection, or make a query.

I'm using a DB2 on zOS
and I've got the connection with the following 2 drivers
db2jcc.jar
db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar

Does anyone know if this is something I have to live with, or is there something I am missing to show all the tables? Also, if people know why I can't edit in-line query results, that'd be awesome to. They seem to be read only.

FYI, schema browser doesn't allow me to do anything either.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At work we use DbVisualizer.  Your mainframe DBA's will need to give your account you are connecting with privileges to see the system catalogs.

[DBVIS](http://www.dbvis.com/)